# How to store extra fields that I don't care about in a Map when deserializing?

Tags: scala, scalatra

This is what I want to do: [Jackson deserialize extra fields as map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156293/jackson-deserialize-extra-fields-as-map), but I haven't gotten it to work.

This is the class I want to deserialize:

```
class MyClass(
           @JsonProperty val name: String,
           @JsonProperty val age: Int,
           @JsonIgnore val other: mutable.HashMap[String, Any] = mutable.HashMap()
         ) {

  @JsonAnyGetter def getOther: mutable.HashMap[String, Any] = other

  @JsonAnySetter def setOther(key: String, value: Any): Unit = {
    other.put(key, value)
  }
}
```

Now the input might be this:

```
{
    "name": "Lisa",
    "age": 42
}
```

And everyting is well. But the input might also be this:

```
{
    "name": "Lisa",
    "age": 42
    "extraProperty": 123
}
```

And in that case I would like to store everything other than `name`/`age` (i.e. `extraProperty` here) into the map, so that I can pass it on to the next service. But it's not working: Nothing appears in the `other` map. I've also tried doing `@(JsonAnyGetter@field) val other: mutable.HashMap[String, Any] = mutable.HashMap()` (which I found here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/308), but it didn't work.

Has anyone gotten this to work with Scalatra?

Comment: You could also keep the json object, possibly without the two "used" fields.

Comment: Perhaps, but there will be many extra fields in a large object tree and I'm not sure how I could "merge that back in" later.